# Lookup value in CSV and return value from 2nd column

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm pulling a server list from SCOM and want to check this list against a CSV which contains the following data:

```
Computername,Collection Name
Server01,NA - All DA Servers - Patching - Cert - Thu 2:00
Server02,NA - All DA Servers - Patching - Prod - Wed 18:00
```

If the server is found, return the Collection Name.  I'm just unsure what would be the best approach.

```psh
Import-Module OperationsManager

New-SCOMManagementGroupConnection -ComputerName SCOMsvr

$PendReboot = Get-ScomAlert -Criteria "Severity = 1 AND ResolutionState < 254 AND Name = 'Pending Reboot'" |
              Select NetbiosComputerName

$data = Import-Csv .\servers2.csv

$table = $data | Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString -Property Computername
```

**Edit** - second attempt code:

```psh
$csv = Import-Csv D:\SCOM-Pend-Reboot.csv

$biglist = Import-Csv D:\servers2.csv

foreach ($line in $csv){
  $server = $line.NetbiosComputerName

  if ($server -eq $biglist.Computername) {
    "$server is in $biglist.'Collection Name'"
  } else {
    "$server is not found!"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you group the CSV data like that you'll have to access the information like this, because the value of the group item contains the `Servername` property as well:

```
$server = 'Server01'
$table[$server].'Collection Name'
```

That only makes sense if your CSV has more than one column. But even then I'd probably prefer a hastable of custom objects so that the server name appears only as the key:

```
$table = @{}
Import-Csv .\servers2.csv | ForEach-Object {
  $table[$_.Computername] = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    'Collection Name' = $_.'Collection Name'
    'other property'  = ...
    ...
  }
}
```

If the CSV has just the two columns it'd be simpler to create the hashtable like this:

```
$table = @{}
Import-Csv .\servers2.csv | ForEach-Object {
  $table[$_.Computername] = $_.'Collection Name'
}
```

So that you can look up the name directly:

```
$server = 'Server01'
$table[$server]
```

Comment: I really appreciate the reply!  Running this returns `Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null` at `$table[$_.Computername] = $_.'Collection Name'`

Comment: @user4317867 You have a blank line in your CSV. Remove it.

Comment: @user4317867 The code I posted imports the CSV and fills a hashtable `$table` with the data. There is no console output generated in the process.

Comment: @user4317867 That sounds like an entirely different question. What are your grouping criteria?

Comment: @user4317867 The need to go to chat usually means that your problem is under-explained in your question. I suggest you either update this question with a more detailed explanation of your input and how you want to handle it, or (probably better) post a new question with your current code and a more detailed explanation of your input and how you want to handle it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98441/discussion-between-user4317867-and-ansgar-wiechers).

Comment: Had to use `$list = Import-Csv D:\file.csv`

`$list.NetbiosComputerName | ForEach-Object { $table[$_] }`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Import-Module OperationsManager

New-SCOMManagementGroupConnection -ComputerName SCOMsvr

$PendReboot = get-scomalert -Criteria "Severity = 1 AND ResolutionState < 254 AND Name = 'Pending Reboot'" | Select NetbiosComputerName

$data = Import-Csv .\servers2.csv

$table = $data | Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString -Property Computername

foreach($server in $PendReboot) {
    if($table.ContainsKey($server)) {
        ($table.$server)."Collection Name"
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried this but got no output.  So I tried making `Get-SCOMAlert` pipe to `Export-CSV` then `$PendReboot = Import-CSV ...` and still got no output.  Running the foreach in console returns `@{NetbiosComputerName=Server101}`

Answer (score 0):

A case of over complicating things.

[Thanks to this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/e935b04e-6ef2-4195-8982-fa5c24d0e0bf/powershell-search-csv-for-multiple-strings-in-column-and-return-matching-rows-in-output-csv?forum=ITCG) my answer was as simple as:

```
IF(-not(Get-SCOMAlert)){Import-Module OperationsManager}

New-SCOMManagementGroupConnection -ComputerName SCOM-Server

Get-SCOMAlert -Criteria "Severity = 1 AND ResolutionState < 254 AND Name = 'Pending'" | Select NetbiosComputerName | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path D:\SCOM-Pend-Reboot.csv

$csv = Get-Content 'D:\SCOM-Pend-Reboot.csv'
Import-Csv D:\servers2.csv | Where {$_ -match $csv.computername} | Sort Computername
```