# Powershell CSV ForEach row search for a cell value in another csv and return a match

Tags: powershell, csv

If this question has been answered elsewhere I apologize. I've been searching for a solution for multiple days. 
I have 2 CSV files. *MasterFile.csv* and *PhoneNumbers.csv* formatted as below.

*MasterFile.csv*

```
SomeData MoreData Phone      LastData

abcdefg hijklmnop 2222222222 qrstuvwx
```

*PhoneNumbers.csv*

```
Client_ID Phone1     Phone2     Phone3

12345     1111111111 2222222222 3333333333
```

For each row in *MasterFile.csv*, I want to search for Phone in *PhoneNumbers.csv* in all 3 columns Phone1, Phone2, and Phone3. I then want to return Client_ID to *MasterFile.csv* in a new column if Phone matches any column.

**Expected Outcome**

```
SomeData MoreData Phone      LastData Client_ID

abcdefg hijklmnop 2222222222 qrstuvwx 12345
```

Comment: Maybe this will be [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256949/lookup-value-in-csv-and-return-value-from-2nd-column)

Comment: if you use `-match` against a $Collection`, PoSh will return the matches [if there are any]. that would give you the object from the PhoneNumbers list. then you can use `[PSCustomObject]` to build a new object that has the wanted props, and finally save that to a new file. if you REALLY want to over-write the source file, do so AFTER you have finished using it ... otherwise you may find yourself garbling your source file. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to create a lookup hashtable from the PhoneNumbers.csv where every phone number in there is the Key and the Client_Id is the value.

```
$master  = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\MasterFile.csv'
$numbers = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\test\PhoneNumbers.csv'

# create a lookup Hashtable from the numbers
$lookup = @{}
$numbers | ForEach-Object {
    $lookup[$_.Phone1] = $_.Client_ID
    $lookup[$_.Phone2] = $_.Client_ID
    $lookup[$_.Phone3] = $_.Client_ID
}

# iterate through the master items and emit an object with the Client_ID attached
$result = $master | ForEach-Object {
    $id = if ($lookup.ContainsKey($_.Phone)) { $lookup[$_.Phone] } else { 'Unknown' }
    $_ | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Client_ID'; Expression = {$id}}
}

#output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to (new) CSV file)
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\MasterFileComplete.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Another approach, again using a lookup hashtable is to combine the three phone numbers using the pipe symbol `|` and use that as key.
This will effectively become a string that can be used with the regex `-match` operator like this:

```
$master  = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\MasterFile.csv'
$numbers = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\test\PhoneNumbers.csv'

# create a lookup Hashtable from the numbers
$lookup = @{}
$numbers | ForEach-Object {
    # combine the numbers with the pipe symbol which is OR in a regex match
    # your phone numbers may have formats with a country code like '+44 12345678'
    # so to be sure, you need to [regex]::Escape() each phone number
    $key = '{0}|{1}|{2}' -f [regex]::Escape($_.Phone1), 
                            [regex]::Escape($_.Phone2), 
                            [regex]::Escape($_.Phone3)
    $lookup[$key] = $_.Client_ID
}

# iterate through the master items and emit an object with the Client_ID attached
$result = $master | ForEach-Object {
    $phone = $_.Phone
    # find the matching phone number using regex
    $key = $lookup.Keys | Where-Object { $phone -match $_ }
    $id = if ($key) { $lookup[$key] } else { 'Unknown' }
    $_ | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Client_ID'; Expression = {$id}}
}

#output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to (new) CSV file)
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\MasterFileComplete.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Depending on what is in your files, the output on screen will look something like

> ```
> SomeData MoreData  Phone      LastData Client_ID
> -------- --------  -----      -------- ---------
> abcdefg  hijklmnop 2222222222 qrstuvwx 12345    
> ijklmno  kjsdhsd   3333333334 qrstuvwx Unknown  
> pqrstuv  qazwsx    5555555555 qrstuvwx 67890
> ```

<sup>P.S. I'm writing out a new CSV file for safety so you do not overwrite your original</sup>

Comment: The first approach was what I needed! Thank you so much!